# Apache Camel: File component moveFailed redelivery strategy

Tags: apache, apache-camel

When a certain endpoint is not available (500 for instance) my queue file is moved to .error directory. I am using the parameter: moveFailed for this.

```
<from uri="file:inbox?autoCreate=true&amp;readLockTimeout=2000&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;preMove=.processing&amp;delete=true&amp;moveFailed=.error&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=50&amp;delay=1000"/>
```

According to: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

> When moving the files to the “fail” location Camel will handle the
>   error and will not pick up the file again.

What is the best approach to implement a redelivery policy/strategy so that the files get picked up again when failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup a retry by redelivering to that certain endpoint component, not to the whole route.

You can do this by specifying number of retries, a delay between retries, and a backoff multiplier if you so wish using an [error handler](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html).

```
onException(RestException.class)
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(100L)
            .backOffMultiplier(1.5)
```

Or setting this in your camel context:

```
<errorHandler id="errorhandler" redeliveryPolicyRef="redeliveryPolicy"/>
<redeliveryPolicyProfile id="redeliveryPolicy" maximumRedeliveries="3" redeliveryDelay="100" backOffMultiplier="1.5" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
```

This way, the file is only delivered to the error folder once it has run out of redelivery attempts.

You could also look at using the [dead letter handler](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html), and putting the file into a queue to be processed later.

Comment: You've already specified it in your file component.
By putting in redelivery attempts in your error handler, the file component is not made aware of the error until all delivery attempts are exhausted, and hence does not move the file to the error folder until then.

Comment: it's not picking up the error handler:
[GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback:141] Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileDeleteProcessStrategy@21c3823b for file: GenericFile[.processing/XXX-local-39727-1510746978560-0-999]

Comment: Ah, I was missing: errorHandlerRef="errorHandler" on my <route>! problem solved. thanks!